# How to setState with Picker in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker, setstate

A feature in my project in province searching but now I'm using typing the name of province and now I want to use Picker in React-native to setState from value that user selected.How can I setState from value that user selected from Picker?

My searching function and constructor.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     currentCity: "Phuket",
     searchText: ""
 };
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const { searchText } = this.state;
 this.refs.modal3.close();
 this.setState({ currentCity: searchText });
}
```

My Searching box and picker.

```
<TextInput
        placeholder="City name"
        ref={el => (this.element = el)}
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={this.state.searchText}
        onChangeText={searchText => this.setState({ searchText })}
      />
      <View>
        <Button style={styles.btn} onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Text style={styles.submitText}>Submit</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
      {//Dropdown Picker
      }
      <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.language}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 200 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ language: itemValue })
        }
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Amnat Charoen" value="1906689" />
        <Picker.Item label="Ang Thong" value="1621034" />
        <Picker.Item label="Bangkok" value="1609350" />
```

Comment: You *seem* to be already doing that `onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          this.setState({ language: itemValue })
        }` also it's either `reactjs` or `react-native` don't use both tags.

Comment: I just copy this section of code from React-native's Doc I don't know how to use it properly can you suggest me please. And If I want to close the picker's form when user selected how can I use handleSubmit in Picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the code you provided in your question i think you are new to react-native. your code is wrong( you just copied & pasted code). this part `selectedValue={this.state.language}` in your `Picker` is wrong because there is no `language` in your `state`.

imagine you have a `Picker` which has list of cities. and you have a variable in state named `selectedCity`.

so your picker would be like this :

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedCity}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
  this.setState({ selectedCity: itemValue })
  }
 >
   <Picker.Item label="city1" value="1" />
   <Picker.Item label="city2" value="2" />
</Picker>
```

this will make a `Picker` listing 2 cities( city1 - city2) and whenever user selects one of them `this.setState()` will be called and `selectedCity` in state will be initialized.

if you want to call `setState` in another method, just instead of

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
      this.setState({ selectedCity: itemValue })
      }
```

use

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
     //call method here!
      }
```